# Actualizar datos con php y Android Studio

Tags: php, mysql, android

Hola a todos quisiera saber como puedo hacer para actualizar los datos de un usuario incluyendo su email.

Este problema se genera en la aplicación al momento de actualizar datos ya registrado, bueno la aplicación la conecte con php y eh agregado un select esto es para verificar el email cuando un usuario quiera cambiar el correo no pueda utilizar un email que pertenezca a otra cuenta.

En este momento la aplicación logra reconocer si el email esta en uso o no, el problema se da cuando quiero actualizar mis otros datos por ejemplo nombre, apellidos, genero y edad no me deja actualizar porque reconoce que su mismo email ya esta en uso, solo permite actualizar si cambio el email pero este pertenece a mi cuenta.

Lo que quiero hacer es poder actualizar los datos pero que no me genere el error que aparece en la imagen, pero que siempre haga la verificación si el email esta en uso o no.

Espero y me de a entender.

Mi código php es este.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $Nombre = $_POST['nombres'];
    $Apellido = $_POST['apellidos'];
    $Genero = $_POST['genero'];
    $Edad = $_POST['edad'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $id = $_POST['id_alumno'];

    require_once 'connect.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE email = '$Email'";
    $check = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($check)) {
        $result["success"] = "0";
        $result["message"] = "El correo electrónico ya esta en uso";
        echo json_encode($result);
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    } else {
    $update = "UPDATE alumnos SET nombres='$Nombre', apellidos='$Apellido', genero='$Genero', edad='$Edad', email='$Email' WHERE id_alumno='$id' ";
    if(mysqli_query($conexion, $update)) {

          $result["success"] = "1";
          $result["message"] = " Los datos ha sido actualizados.";

          echo json_encode($result);
          mysqli_close($conexion);
      }
}
}
?>
```

Java

```
private void GuardarDetallesUsuario() {

    final String nombres = this.nombres.getText().toString().trim();
    final String apellidos = this.apellidos.getText().toString().trim();
    final String genero = this.genero.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
    final String edad = this.edad.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = this.email.getText().toString().trim();
    final String id_alumno = getId_alumno;

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Actualizando...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_EDITAR,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");

                        if (success.equals("1")) {
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Los datos han sido actualizados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            sessionManager.createSession(nombres, apellidos, genero, edad, email, id_alumno);
                        }
                        if (success.equals("0")){
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Ya existe una cuenta con este correo electrónico.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            sessionManager.createSession(nombres, apellidos, genero, edad, email, id_alumno);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error al actualizar. Intentelo nuevamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No hay conexión ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("nombres", nombres);
            params.put("apellidos", apellidos);
            params.put("genero", genero);
            params.put("edad", edad);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("id_alumno", id_alumno);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Error:

El email que aparece en la imagen es el que uso para registrarse y no el de otra cuenta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La explicación se convirtió en un trabalenguas. ¿Podrías explicarlo sencillamente, sin liarte tanto: *quiero tal y tal cosa*, *he intentando hacer tal cosa*, *tengo error en tal cosa o funciona de esta manera*. Pulsa en [edit] para aclarar la pregunta.

Comment: Una forma de solucionarlo es que la tabla administre si se repite el dato con un `UNIQUE INDEX` y cuando la consulta te devuelva el error 1062, enviar un mensaje del dato duplicado

Answer (score 1):

en primer lugar creo que el primer error està en la consulta sql:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos SET email = '$Email'";
```

Deberias modificar SET por WHERE para buscar si existe algun alumno con el mismo email.

En el siguiente if yo modificaria el código añadiendo >0 para comprovar si encuentras uno o más registros con la condicion que has buscado. A partir de aquí si has encontrado uno o más registros no actualizas nada y si al contrario no hay nongún alumno con este email executas el código para actualizar los datos.

Te dejo el código por si te sirve.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$Nombre = $_POST['nombres'];
$Apellido = $_POST['apellidos'];
$Genero = $_POST['genero'];
$Edad = $_POST['edad'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$id = $_POST['id_alumno'];

require_once 'connect.php';

//Modificar set por where para buscar y no modificar
$sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE email = '$Email'";
$check = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

//Si encontramos un resultado es que el correo ya existe
if (mysqli_num_rows($check)>0) {
    $result["message"] = "El correo electrónico ya esta en uso";
    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}
// Si no encontramos ninguno procedemos a la modificacion de los datos 
else {
$update = "UPDATE alumnos SET nombres='$Nombre', apellidos='$Apellido', genero='$Genero', edad='$Edad', email='$Email' WHERE id_alumno='$id' ";
if(mysqli_query($conexion, $update)) {
      $result["message"] = " Los datos ha sido actualizados.";
      echo json_encode($result);
      mysqli_close($conexion);
  }
else{
    $result["success"] = "1";
    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero te sugerimos agregar una explicación de lo que realiza el código o como ayuda a resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [answer] y edita tu respuesta por favor ya que ha sido marcada como de "Baja calidad", saludos.